# Is there a way to reduce or eliminate render time? When changing the color of an animated object

Tags: rendering, animation

I've created an animation of spinning coin and I'm trying to figure out if theres anyway I can reduce or eliminate the render time when I change the color of the coin.

I want to create several color variations of the same animation, and I am currently re-rendering the entire animation each time I make a small color change(Which is over an hour each time). Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

[image]

Comment: If you're not worried about indirect lighting you can use cryptomatte in the compositor to change materials.

Comment: To begin with, If all you render is the coin in your post, an hour seems quite excessive unless you have a big frame range to render and/or a low end hardware. Maybe you should investigate that too.... That being said, you could render it once in greyscale, then colorize it with a color ramp in comp (just exclude the drop shadow).